# Как сделать такие линии между блоками?

Tags: html, css

Имеется такая вёрстка блоков:

```css
* {
width:576px;
}
.item {
    border: 1px #dededc solid;
    height: 232px;
}

#four-blocks {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#four-blocks .item {
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#four-blocks .item:nth-child(1), .item:nth-child(3){
    margin-right: 11px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 3px 0 3px coral;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="four-blocks">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
```

Нужно, чтобы по горизонтали и по вертикали блоки отделяла линия, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать? Я что-то не соображу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью псевдокласса [`:nth-child`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child) и псевдоэлементов [`:before`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before) и [`:after`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after)

```css
#four-blocks {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 580px;
}

#four-blocks .item {
  border: 1px #dededc solid;
  height: 232px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
}

#four-blocks .item:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

#four-blocks .item:nth-child(-n + 2):before {
  content: '';
  background: #F2F2F0;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  width: 100%;
}

#four-blocks .item:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

#four-blocks .item:nth-child(2n + 1):after {
  content: '';
  background: #F2F2F0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="four-blocks">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как раз хотел сделать через них, но решение не приходило на ум. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, я решил вашу задачу так, добавил в двух блоках по каждой еще две блоки. и дал им абсолютное позиционирование от родительского блока, после этого уже можем переместить их куда нам нужно.
Нашими линиями будут блоки `<div>` с классами `item`.

```css
#four-blocks{
  width: 180px;
}
#four-blocks .item_cont{
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px #dededc solid;
}
#four-blocks .item_cont .item{
  position: absolute;
  background: #dededc;
}
#four-blocks .item_cont .item:nth-child(1){
  width: 80px;
  height: 1px;
}
#four-blocks .item_cont .item:nth-child(2){
  width: 1px;
  height: 80px;  
}
#four-blocks .item_cont:first-child .item:nth-child(1){  
  bottom: -7px;
}
#four-blocks .item_cont:first-child .item:nth-child(2){
  right: -7px;
}

#four-blocks .item_cont:last-child .item:nth-child(1){
  top: -7px;
}
#four-blocks .item_cont:last-child .item:nth-child(2){
  left: -7px;
}


#four-blocks {
    overflow: hidden;
}


#four-blocks .item_cont:nth-child(1), .item_cont:nth-child(3){
    margin-right: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="four-blocks">
    <div class="item_cont">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item_cont"></div>
    <div class="item_cont"></div>
    <div class="item_cont">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Перфекционисты негодуют - [пиксел разница](https://www.screencast.com/t/15O6zCnFW)

Comment: @AGS17 пусть решает `Byulent` ему помогло решение или нет, дело не в пикселе а в логике. А если можете лучше пожалуйста, не кто не мешает вам дать новый ответ на вопрос.